# Display and print a fillable pdf

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin.android

**What I want to archive:**
I scanned a transport protocol which has check boxes and text fields on it. I want to be able to display it in an Android app, fill in the needed data digital and make a new PDF (with a transparent background) out the digital added strings and checks (the empty protocol is already pre-printed => I just want to add the data).

**What I tried:**
I made a fill able PDF in Adobe Acrobat but I'm not able to display it in the app. I tried to embed it into a html file and  display it like this (the .html and the .pdf file are both in the "Assets" directory)([the tutorial I followed](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/load_local_content/)):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <embed src="/TransportReport.pdf" width="500px" height="375px">
</body>
</html>

View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TransportReport, container, false);
view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.wv_transportReport_id).LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/TransportReport.html");
```

but I alwas get this error ("TEST" gets displayed):

```
11-11 21:48:10.183 E/eglCodecCommon( 4135): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
11-11 21:48:10.243 E/eglCodecCommon( 4135): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
11-11 21:48:10.243 E/eglCodecCommon( 4135): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
```

And for the second part: Is it possible to extract the filled in data and "convert" it to a new PDF with a blank background? If not, does someone have a better idea how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance for every suggestion/solution.

Comment: Do you need to write data and save as PDF?

Comment: No,but this seemed to me to be the cleanest way to add the digital interface to the scanned protocol.